Angular 18 angular/fire not initializing
I have installed :
"@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",

My main.ts :
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Then i initializeApp in my app.config.ts :
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
              provideRouter(routes, inMemoryScrollingFeature),
              provideAnimations(),
              provideStore(reducers),
              provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
              provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
              provideEffects([]),
              provideRouterStore(),
              provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([mainInterceptor])), 
              MessageService,
              provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
              provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
                  enabled: !isDevMode(),
                  registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }), provideAnimationsAsync(),


  ]
};

And then i try to listen to notifications in my app.component.ts :
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.platform.isBrowser){
      this.requestPermission();
      this.listen();
    }
  }

  requestPermission() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();

getToken(messaging, {
  vapidKey: environment.vapidKey
}).then(
  (currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log('Your token is: ', currentToken);
      
    } else {
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    }
  }
).catch((error) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', error.message);
})


 }

  listen() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
      this.message = payload;
    })
  }

And i get the following error - why ? :

Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call
initializeApp() first (app/no-app).


please share main.ts code and app.config.ts or app.module.ts

There is no app.module.ts because its angular 18. Its all in app.config.ts.  Updated teh code in my question with main.ts and full app.config.ts

do you have a github repo to reproduce the issue? code looks fine also do a console.log of environment, or try hard coding the credentials

No it's private, but the environment variable is fine

I think this private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging in the constructor should be used instead of const messaging = getMessaging(); because this should be inside the providers array.

The documentation you provided is not for angular 17 or 18. Angular 17/18 does not use modules.

@PoketJoker try private messaging:Messaging docs

As stated in the documentation here, you should inject Messaging instead of calling getMessage:
  constructor(private msg: Messaging){
    Notification.requestPermission().then(
    (notificationPermissions: NotificationPermission) => {
      if (notificationPermissions === "granted") {
        console.log("Granted");
      }
      if (notificationPermissions === "denied") {
        console.log("Denied");
      }
    });

